# Unidentified 404 error

Tags: 404-error

I have created a new WordPress site and installed rank math for SEO. In 404 Monitor, I am getting some logs, but I couldn’t understand after making research what that means and why is this happening. Can you help me to solve it, please? Why this is happening and how can I solve it?

[image: Screen shots of the 404 Monitor]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know 404 monitor: does it show you the IP address that made the request too? This could be bots scanning your site for known vulnerabilities to exploit and not genuine traffic. If so you'd see large blocks of failed requests with the same IP address. Does 404 monitor help you filter those out? Is 404 monitor part of Rank Math? It might be worth asking them for help.

Comment: That's the all information I have. No IP address. I have asked them but they didn't give me specific answer just forward me to classic 404 error handling page. Yes 404 monitor is part of Rank Math.

Comment: Huh, that's not very helpful, and without that I'm not sure it's much use - unless you magically get no bot traffic. You probably also have access logs for your site from your server or host that you can look at too which will contain the IP addresses etc. (unless you're behind a reverse proxy and something's configured wrong).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The 404 Montior in RankMath does not include the IP address (even in advanced mode). You need to rely on the Referrer and the User-Agent column to determine if it's a bot or a user. Sometimes if you look at the Access Time column you can see they're being requested within milliseconds of each other.

From looking at the output you have captured, it's a bot.

The thing with 404 Errors is that you only need to redirect the ones that are for pages that you have removed and actually want to show a different page.

404 Errors inherently are not a bad thing - they just tell you something doesn't exist anymore.

The ones on your list all look like junk requests so just ignore them (or you can use the checkbox and delete them from your list).  These are just random requests made by bots and scripts checking if something exists so they could potentially exploit it later.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a variety of reasons, such as typos in the URL, a broken link, or a page that has been deleted or moved.

The Rank Math plugin includes a feature called "404 Monitor" that tracks these errors and logs them for you to review. This can be useful for identifying and fixing broken links or other issues that may be causing 404 errors on your site.

To fix a 404 error, you can try the following steps:

1. Check the URL for typos or other mistakes. Make sure that the URL is correct and leads to a valid page on your site.
2. Check for broken links. If you have linked to a page on your site that no longer exists, the link will result in a 404 error. To fix this, you can update the link to point to a valid page or remove the link altogether.
3. Check for redirects. If you have recently moved or deleted a page, you may have set up a redirect to a new URL. Make sure that the redirect is working properly and is directing users to the correct page.
4. Check for plugin or theme conflicts. If you have recently installed or updated a plugin or theme, it could be causing issues with your site. Try deactivating the plugin or switching to a default theme to see if that resolves the issue.

If you are still unable to fix the 404 errors after trying these steps, you may need to seek further assistance from your hosting provider or a WordPress developer.